# WCF - Modify response message

Tags: wcf

My WCF service has a message contract called `ProductResponseMessage`.

This message contains a data contract `ProductResponse`, which in turn contains many data members.

One of the data contract is `Person` which has a data member `SocialSecurityNumber`. This a 11 digit number. This person object may be present inside other data contracts.

My requirement is that I am not suppose to show the 11 digits all the time to the client. If the client has access to view full 11 digits (configured with yes no for each client) or else it should be shown as last 6 digits padded with x. (Like 54645XXXXXX).

This SSN value comes from database and I would need the full number inside my service for various purposes.

What would be the right approach in WCF for doing this? I have read about message inspectors.

Do I need to use it? Or is there any other approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>One option would be:</strike>

- your WCF service doesn't care - it always returns the full 11 digits
- your front end (web site, Winforms app - whatever you have) deals with either showing or suppressing the SSN number

This makes your service the simplest - it just returns the data all the time.

If you want to change this, then I would think you would have to send some indication to your service when calling it (e.g. as a `[MessageHeader]` element in your request) that tells the service what to do - return the whole 11 digits, only parts of it, or nothing at all. If you do this, handle in in the service code (the code that implements your service contract).

**Update:** OK, so you want to service to make that decision. In that case, I'd probably do it like this:

- retrieve the full SSN into a private variable in my service - you said you need to full SSN for various things anyway
- have a property called `DisplaySSN` or something (string)
- based on the user name passed in with the request, determine what that `DisplaySSN` can be (the full SSN, parts "blacked" out with `XXXX`, nothing at all) and set that property accordingly

So I would definitely do this on the service side right away - don't handle it using a message inspector (that might be there or might not be....)

Comment: I dont want the web site to handle this.My service has to decide this based on a configuration defined database for each username passed in the request header.